# Batch that sets a variable equal to a line in a text file, run several commands, repeat with next line

Tags: batch-file, text, cmd, repeat

I have over 2 million folders split up across different locations. These folders contain old archives of photos labeled by work order number. I created a batch file a while back that automatically searches through these folders for a specific folders based on user input. Right now i have it only returning one order at a time.

I want to modify the script to restore about 200 folders to a location on my desktop. I have a list of these folders in a text file. I tried to run my script, but it only returns the first order in the text file. I need it to loop through and move on to the next line each time. If the folder cannot be found, I would like it to just move on to the next line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
:start
@echo off

::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Sets the order number::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::

for /F %%G IN (E:\Desktop\test.txt) DO set Name=%%G

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::Locates the order and sets the location variable to the directory where the order is stored::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

if exist "\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Feb2012\%name%" set location=\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Feb2012&& goto restore
if exist "\\10.10.32.33\Backups\March2012\%name%" set location=\\10.10.32.33\Backups\March2012&& goto restore
if exist "\\10.10.32.33\Backups\Archive\%name%" set location=\\10.10.32.33\Backups\Archive&& goto restore
if exist "\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order4\%name%" set location=\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order4&& goto restore
if exist "\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order3\%name%" set location=\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order3&& goto restore
if exist "\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order2\%name%" set location=\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order2&& goto restore
if exist "\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order1\%name%" set location=\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order1&& goto restore
if exist "\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order\%name%" set location=\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order&& goto restore
if exist "\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order5\%name%" set location=\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order5&& goto restore
if exist "\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order6\%name%" set location=\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order6&& goto restore
if exist "\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order7\%name%" set location=\\10.10.32.33\Backups\USB_Order_Backup\Order7&& goto restore


:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::If the order cannot be found, the failure message will be displayed::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:fail
goto start

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::Restores the missing photos::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:restore
xcopy %location%\%name% "E:\Desktop\Restored Photos\%name%" /s /i /e /x /h
goto start
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:start
@echo off


for /F %%G IN (E:\Desktop\test.txt) DO (
    set "locationFound="
    for %%a in (
        USB_Order_Backup\Feb2012
        March2012
        Archive
        USB_Order_Backup\Order4
        USB_Order_Backup\Order3
        USB_Order_Backup\Order2
        USB_Order_Backup\Order1
        USB_Order_Backup\Order
        USB_Order_Backup\Order5
        USB_Order_Backup\Order6
        USB_Order_Backup\Order7
    ) do if not defined locationFound if exist "\\10.10.32.33\Backups\%%a\%%G" (
        set "locationFound=1"
        xcopy "\\10.10.32.33\Backups\%%a\%%G" "E:\Desktop\Restored Photos\%%G" /s /i /e /x /h
    )
    if not defined locationFound (
        echo %%G not found 
    )
)
```

Comment: You will need delayed expansion in your XCOPY statement as written. I would use the string constants and FOR variables directly. Then you don't need delayed expansion. The location value would not matter, it just needs to be defined once you locate the folder. I like to use a value of 1.

Comment: @Magoo, thank you. I must be blind. Maybe i should not answer anything until tomorrow.